# What happens if I don't assign new Image in a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get some understanding about **new image**. Would I be able to create a variable that is supposed to hold an image without assigning a new image object to it? I know you don't have to assign **new array** when creating an array or **new object** creating a new object. Is assigning new image to a variable that you are going to hold a image in an old method or do I still need to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are shorthand examples for `new Array()` = `[]` and `new Object()` = `{}`, but there is no known shorthand/shortcut for `new Image()`. That is actually part of the HTML 5 spec, where this code comes from the W3C website:

```
image = new Image( [ width [, height ] ] )
```

> Returns a new img element, with the width and height attributes set to
>   the values passed in the relevant arguments, if applicable.

See the green box at this link (scroll up slightly): https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-image

So every JS example on the web seems to be using `new Image()` in the code examples. However, you can use longhand, like this & assign properties to it.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = '...';
img.height = 123;
img.width = 456;
```

It's not as cool as "()", because these keyboard pairs are already taken: `[]`, `{}` and `()`. Those are for array, object & function parameters, respectively. This looks more like an HTML tag: `<>`. So there really isn't anything left on the keyboard, which could create a group for a shortcut / shorthand for `new Image()`.

Here are a few JS shorthand links:

1. http://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators

Answer (score 0):

@Clomp does a good explanation. But here is another example on how to use this knowledge.

```
// Create new image element
var image = new Image( 100, 100 );

// Add an image source to element
image.src = 'http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/130000/velka/blue-tit-bird-clipart.jpg';

// Output new image element to console  
console.log(image);

// Add image element to body
$('body').html(image);
```

https://jsbin.com/medohiquti/edit?html,js,output